# Process gets killed automatically in Fedora

Tags: linux, process

I have a Automation process which is a java program running on fedora 6/14. A problem that I face very frequently is that this process is getting killed automatically. Ideally this process has been programmed to run at-least for 12-14 hours. But somewhere in between it gets killed. I have checked whether OOM Killer was the root cause, but there aren't any tracelogs in /var/log/messages to suggest that.

Any other bright ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the output and error output so you can see what's happening. If you're just running the program in the background, you could use redirection

```
program >out 2>errs &
```

Probably it's a memory leak, but you won't know for sure without capturing the errors.

Comment: Ok. Will try this out the next time I run the process and see if I get anything!